# is it possible to let a piece of code to run only during debug?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Does python provide functionality that only allow a piece of code to run during debug, a bit like preprocessor in c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a builtin constant [`__debug__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#__debug__) that can be used for this purpose.

```
python -O something.py  # __debug__ == False
python something.py  #  __debug__ == True
```

Note that there is also the `assert` statement which can be optimized out completely. . .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the logger module (which is always great) and check for the log-level.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

For example by using the `getEffectiveLevel()`:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel

This way you have some other nifty features like log messages with different levels…